# Installing RetroPie

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, retropie

I currently have a Raspbian desktop computer based on Raspberry Pi 4. I am planning to install retropie. Bought a new sd card for this purpose to have a dedicated Retropie sd card. Do I need to buy a new Raspberry Pi to install Retropie if I intend to keep Raspbian? Or is it just an installation onto the SD card? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind , what types of games are you going to play? NDS,MAME or PSP? or something else?

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to buy a new Raspberry Pi.

Its just an installation onto the sd card. Swap as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can install those in different memory card and use it whenever you wish to. You just have to change the memory card which holds your file system(the card that has the OS installed in it).You do not need to buy another raspberry Pi for that. You should make some memory cards with different OS.